# 90's weekly fantasy release collection

Tags: story-identification

When growing up in South Africa in the 90's I used to get a weekly [partwork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partwork) magazine about a magical world. Each issue came with collectible cards and other parts. I remember they would keep them for me at [CNA](https://www.cna.co.za/) to get when I had enough pocket money.

There weren't *any* other releases even slightly like it, which should help to narrow it down :-)

Comment: Tracking down a partwork should be pretty easy but you'll need to improve the description. What sort of magical world was it? What sort of cards/parts did it come with?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [The Ancestral Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ancestral_Trail).

I got the first series and bits of the second. It was really good.

> **The Ancestral Trail** is a now out-of-print partwork magazine that was originally published by Marshall Cavendish in the United Kingdom, Australia, South Africa, parts of Europe and New Zealand between 1992 and 1994. There was also a computer game compiled in both DOS and Amiga formats.
>
> The Ancestral Trail Partworks were then based on a manuscript initially written by Frank Graves, which split into two halves of 26 issues each. The first half partwork adaption, written by Fergus Fleming, takes place in the Ancestral World and describes Richard's struggle to restore good to the world. The second part, written by Ian Probert, takes place within the Cyber Dimension. It deals with Richard's attempts to fight evil while also attempting to return home. Each issue centered on an adventure against a particular adversary, and each issue ended on a cliffhanger. The Partworks were also published in several languages like in Germany (Im Reich der Urwesen) and Italy (La Storia Ancestrale).
>
> The Ancestral Trail was illustrated by Julek Heller and Adam Heller. Computer-generated graphics were provided by Mehau Kulyk for issues #27 through #52.

Comment: Check out [How to write a good story-ID answer?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/21267) for tips on what point to include in your answer.